# How to show array value into input field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

Hi can someone help me?

I have more than 30 arrays which store 51 value in each array.
I sum each of array value and then I get 1 array with 51 value.

Example (final result):
array1 = ["value1,value2,value3....value50,value51"];

I want the array value show in each of input fields, which I should have 51 empty input fields to match the total value of array1.

Because my array value are too many, I will use 5 value and 5 input fields here.

```
<input name="input" value="" onchange="submit()" id="input"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array2"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array3"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array4"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array5"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array6"/><br>
```

```
function submit() {     
    var x = [2,4,6,8,10];
    var z = document.getElementByName("array");

    //i stuck here ***
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    }   
}
```

Test and follow some method out there and still not working.
Maybe im using the wrong codes.

The result be like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXwYb.png)

```
value 2 in input field id="array2"
value 4 in input field id="array3"
value 6 in input field id="array4"
value 8 in input field id="array5"
value 10 in input field id="array6"
```

- Please dont mind the onchange event because my actual code not using button to trigger the event.
- Sorry for my bad english xD

Comment: `z[i].value = x[i]` , but you're missing an 's' in `getElementsByName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all your input elements by name:

```js
var x = [2,4,6,8,10];
var z = document.getElementsByName("array");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  z[i].value = x[i]
}
```

```html
<input name="array" value="" id="array2"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array3"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array4"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array5"/><br> 
<input name="array" value="" id="array6"/><br>
```

Comment: yes, it is working perfectly. Thx @sonEtLumiere. Now im still searching around about how to short writing the code, because I have 31 arrays and 51 inputs area. Wish I had found simple writing code to invoked each html class with their unique ID, without writing 82 lines of same var object = ...getElementByID("id")...(<< maybe I open a question here about this xD)  btw thanks ^^